# Cakephp why is $user is being false while trying to login

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to create a login and register page with cakephp 3.8. I have successfully created the register page and all the data is input in the database, but once I tried the login, it does not work every time. I don't have any errors that I can see. Every time I input the email and password, it says "Invalid email or password, try again".

The code is below:

UserController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
 public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow('add');
    $this->Auth->allow(['add', 'logout']);
}

public function register()
{
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // Prior to 3.4.0 $this->request->data() was used.
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'register']);
        }
        $this->Flash->_error_(__('Unable to add the user.'));
    }
    $this->set('user', $user);
}



public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->_error_(__('Invalid email or password, try again'));
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
}
```

AppController.php

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
        'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
    ]);
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'register'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ]
    ]);
}

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'display','register']);
}
```

User.php

```
 protected function _setPassword($password)
   {
      if (strlen($password) > 0) {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
}
```

AppCotroller.php

```
 public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
        'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
    ]);
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'register'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ],
        'authenticate'=>[
            'Form'=>[
                'fields'=>['email'=>'email','password'=>'password']
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'display','register','add']);
    $this->set('email',$this->Auth->user('email'));
}
```

login.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<fieldset>
   <legend><?= __('Please enter your email and password') ?></legend>
   <?= $this->Form->control('email') ?>
   <?= $this->Form->control('password') ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Comment: Please include the code where you [configure your Auth component](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers), particularly where you tell it to use `email` instead of `username` as the identification field.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I added it thanks

Comment: Create new user using this->Auth->allow('add'), then check again.

Comment: @AlimonKarim where do I need to put it?

Comment: It is likely that your hashed password is not completely saved because password field is not set correctly in the database . Try VARCHAR 60, and save new password.

Comment: @Salines still no

Answer (score 0):

Your field configuration needs to tell it what field to use as the username:

```
'fields'=>['username'=>'email','password'=>'password']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your AppController initialize function()

```
        'authorize' => ['Controller'], //tell application to check each and every controller request for valid authorization
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'userModel' => 'Users',
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password',
                    'status' => 1
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
```

And please allow the login function also (in your user controller)

```
$this->Auth->allow(['add', 'logout', 'login']);
```

Comment: @Alastair Can you give me some error? it will be easy to help you.

Comment: you can dump() or pr() the entity or data that you use for trying login.